# In hydra, can I interpolate config from a file without using the defaults list?

Tags: fb-hydra

Say I have a directory `utility_configs` that has a bunch of different configurations for different things that are useful in different situations.  And then I want to be able to use these different configs in different places.  For instance, maybe my model has many different places where I need something that is an "encoder" (really just a bit of network that maps an input to an output).  I might have vary different encoders in my `utility_configs` directory, and I would like to be able to specify any of them anyplace I need an encoder (possibly then adjusting the number of input and output channels or other parameters).  I am not seeing how to do this straightforwardly since it seems like the only way you can get data from a different file is using the defaults list.  But that's not really a good fit here since I might need multiple different things from `utility_configs` and in multiple different places (including subconfigs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot interpolate into a file. Interpolation works on the current config object.
Hydra can compose the config for you, after which you can use interpolation.

You have multiple options:

1. Have more than one primary config (with a defaults list). You can override which primary config to use via the [command line](https://hydra.cc/docs/advanced/hydra-command-line-flags/) (`--config-name|-cn`).
2. Construct your defaults list in an ad-hoc manner via the command line using the `+GROUP=OPTION` notation (see [this](https://hydra.cc/docs/tutorials/basic/your_first_app/config_groups/)).

About using a config in different places, take a look at [config packages](https://hydra.cc/docs/advanced/overriding_packages/) - which allows you to relocate the content of a config in the composed config object.

I recommend going with 1.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a chance that some kind of file inclusion method will be added in the future? It doesn't seem like either option is very good for this case. Regarding multiple primary configs, I already have multiple primary configs, and I would like to find ways to reduce the number of them or at least to reduce code duplication between them

Comment: Another issue I'm hitting that I guess is related to interpolations not knowing about files is that in subconfigs there is apparently no way to resolve variables relative to the subconfig.  I either have to use absolute paths or very complicated relative paths, right?

Comment: You can refactor your configs to contain just the defaults list. You can also have a Defaults List in sub configs to further improve reuse.

Comment: Google OmegaConf relative interpolation. If you have more questions submit them separately.

Comment: You might find this useful as a pattern to improve reuse: https://hydra.cc/docs/patterns/configuring_experiments/